# How do I setup two NIC's on Hyper-V VM, one for physical network and one for internet access via NAT?

Tags: hyper-v, nat

I am running Hyper-V on a physical Windows 2019 server with a dual NIC. NIC #1 is connected to my office network, which is in turn, is connected to the internet. NIC #2 is connected to a separate physical desktop switch that has other physical PCs connected to it.

On the Hyper-V Server I am running a single VM which will act as DHCP, DNS and a Web Server for the Test Network. We are running multiple test sites on IIS and use the DNS to direct the test PCs to the local sites instead of the live ones. The VM connects to the physical switch via NIC #2 of the Host Machine.

My Host can access the internet fine but I want to set it up so that the VM Server and the PCs connected to the Test Network can access the internet through NIC #1 on the host using NAT.

The reason I want to do it this way is because when we do offline testing, I can simply unplug NIC #1 and everything will keep functioning but with no connection to the outside world. When I want to update the test PCs I can simply plug in NIC #1 and all the PCs and VM will be able to connect to the internet.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7P20.png)

I tried following this https://petri.com/using-nat-virtual-switch-hyper-v/ but I cant seem to get either the Virtual Machine OR the Test PCs to access the internet? I think the article I followed might be wrong for my setup as I have 2 separate NICs?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my use case, it's almost identical as yours.

#### Facts

Two physical NICs are connected to the Hyper-V host.

`NIC1`: subnet `10.0.0.0/24`, this is the Internet enabled network

`NIC2`: subnet `192.168.100.0/24`, no Internet access

Goal: enable Internet access for the `NIC2` subnet by translating traffic to the `NIC1` subnet

#### Solution

1. Create an external Hyper-V switch named `vEthernet (external)`, and connect it to `NIC2`. I used the Hyper-V manager.
2. Create a new IP address for the newly created switch/interface. It will serve as the default gateway for the `NIC2` subnet.

   ```perl
   PS > New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.100.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceAlias `vEthernet (external)`
   ```
3. Create the NAT network*

   ```perl
   PS > New-NetNAT -Name `NATNetwork` -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.100.0/24
   ```
4. Assign the endpoints from the `192.168.100.0/24` subnet with `192.168.100.1` as the gateway, add a DNS server of your choice and enjoy Internet connectivity.

*) interestingly, I didn't have to specify `ExternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix`, I assume it implicitly used the default gateway of the host.